# Riesz representation theorem for variational equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, riesz-representation-theorem

In a paper on solving PDE's I recently encountered following setting. Let $X$ be Hilbert space and $a:X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded symmetric positive definite bilinearform and $L:X \to \mathbb{R}$ a bounded linearform. Now the claim is there exists a unique $u \in X$ such that
$$a(u,v)=L(v)\quad \text{for all }v \in X $$
and $||u||_a=||L||_{a*}$. Where $||v||_a:=\sqrt{a(v,v)}$ and $||\cdot||_{a*}$ is the dual norm induced by $a$.

I have been trying to prove this without success and I'm starting to doubt the claim. The Riesz rep. thm. requires completeness of the space, but boundedness of $a$ only implies that $||\cdot||_a$ is coarser than $||\cdot||_X$. For norm equivalence, which would give use completeness of $X$ with respect to $||\cdot||_a$, we would require the additional property of coercivity for $a$.

Also continuity of $L$ with respect to $||\cdot||_X$ does not imply continuity w.r.t. $||\cdot||_a$, since that is only the case if $||\cdot||_a$ is finer than $||\cdot||_X$. Thus it is also not clear if $L$ is in the dual of $X$ w.r.t. $||\cdot||_a$, i.e. if $||L||_{a*}$ is well-defined.

Any hints on the proof or rebuttle to my argument would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false as stated.  Let $X = l^2(\Bbb{N}^+, \Bbb{R})$, and $a, L$ defined by
$$a(u, v) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u_n v_n}{n}$$
$$L(v) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{v_n}{n}$$
If you had a $u^0$ such that $\forall v\; a(u^0, v) = L(v)$, by putting in basis vectors, you'd have to have $\forall n\;u^0_n = 1$, which is not in $X$.

Comment: What about choosing $u_1 = L(v)/v_1$ and $u_n = 0$ for $n>1$? Then $a(u,v)=\frac{L(v)v_1}{v_1}=L(v)$.

Comment: @mz_:  you need one $u^0$ to work for all $v$, not one per $v$.